# Pygame : having trouble with implementing movement with vectors

Tags: movement, vector, python, pygame

I've been struggling a lot to learn how to use vectors in programming. Now I've successfully made my own vector class but I still can't use vectors for movement.

This is my class :

```
class MyVector2(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.tuple = (self.x, self.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.x}, {self.y})"

    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)

    def normalize(self):
        self.x /= self.magnitude
        self.y /= self.magnitude

    @staticmethod
    def create_path(destination, pos):
        return MyVector2(destination.x - pos.x, destination.y - pos.y)

    @staticmethod
    def dot(v1, v2):
        return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y
```

(there are also other methods for the operations (+/*-) that I don't need to copy here)

My problem with movement is that the object I want to move doesn't stop at the destination but continues moving infinitely :

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = 100, 80
        self.speed = 0.1
        self.pos = MyVector2(self.x, self.y)
        self.img = img
        self.moving = True

    def blit(self):
        screen.blit(self.img, (self.pos.tuple))

obj = Obj()
dest = MyVector2(150, 130)
path = MyVector2.create_path(dest, obj.pos)
path.normalize()
while True:
    obj.blit()
    if obj.moving:
        obj.pos += path * obj.speed
    if dest == obj.pos:
        obj.moving = False
```

I also think that my way of using vectors to move objects is bad, so please provide me with a professional one.

Comment: You're overshooting; you need to check if the `path * obj.speed` brings you further away from your destination, and if it does, stop at your destination...

Comment: My suspicion here is `dest == obj.pos` - is this ever evaluating as true? It looks to me like you'll want a distance check here instead. Like `distanceBetween(dest, obj.pos) < obj.speed`

Comment: @Vaillancourt Isn't there a better way to do that ?

Comment: Try what DMGregory suggests, if this condition is "True" then you've reached your destination, and you should set the obj.pos directly to dest instead of adding a translation.

Comment: Also, please note that, in general, comparing floating point values (like `dest == obj.pos`) is rarely useful/relevant in game programming because of how data is stored internally by the computer. You should use something like an `equivalent` or [`approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) function which lets you decide if they're "close enough" for your needs (some implementations have three parameters: the two values to compare and the "range" (epsilon), which is often set to a default value).

Comment: @Vaillancourt they are two Vectors (instances of that vector class) not floats

Comment: @Vaillancourt, @DMGregory's solution didn't work. In fact, the distance is never less than ``obj.speed``

Comment: Yes, I understand that, though their internal values are floats, so assuming that you create a function that will handle floats such as this (pseudocode): `equivalent(a, b, epsilon = 0.00001) : return abs(a - b) < epsilon`, you can add an equivalent function to your vector class such as this (pseudocode): `equivalent(self, other, epsilon = 0.00001) : return equivalent(self.x, other.x, epsilon) and equivalent(self.y, other.y, epsilon)`.

Comment: If you tried another approach, please update the question so that we know what you've tried a bit more clearly.

Comment: Couldn't you provide me with what a pygame professional would do in a situation where he needs to implement movement with vectors instead of fixing my code ? Because that's my goal of this post as I have searched a lot about this topic in vain and the code shown in the post is just my attempt.

Comment: I just found that ``distanceBetween(dest, obj.pos)`` is never too low for some reason

Comment: I can't provide code, no, unfortunately, I don't have time for this nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine has found the issue for my code and it was related to the Vector class :

```
def normalize(self):
    self.x /= self.magnitude
    self.y /= self.magnitude
```

Here in the `normalize()` function, once the `self.x` value gets divided by the magnitude, the magnitude changes as it is related to it. So this means the `self.y` value will be then divided by the 'new' magnitude and this will lead to a disorder.

Therefore, the solution is this :

```
def normalize(self):
    m = self.magnitude
    self.x /= m
    self.y /= m
```

That will prevent the problem from happening by saving the magnitude in a variable inside the `normalize()` function. And after trying this, everything worked well and I successfully implemented vector movement in pygame !

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting this, you might consider accepting the answer!